# Unpacking a Tuple of Option in scala

Tags: scala, tuples

I have two Option[BigDecimal] vals that I would like to perform an operation on. I am trying to do this via map.

```
(a,b) map {case(a1: BigDecimal, b1: BigDecimal) => a + b
       case _ => 0}
```

but apparently I can't use a map on Tuple of optionals. Does anyone have any idea how to achieve that using map?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to use `map` for this? It seems that you just want to add two `Option[BigDecimal]` values, and you don't need to use `map` or `match` for that. Is this perhaps an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

Comment: Not really, if one value is missing I would like to return 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you can use `match`

```
  (v1, v2) match {
    case (Some(a), Some(b)) => a + b
    case _ => 0
  }
```

If both `v1` and `v2` is present then returns sum, returns `0` otherwise.

**UPDATE:**
In case you want sum of all present element you can do this:

```
val result = Seq(value._1, value._2)
  .flatten
  .fold[Integer](0)((a, b) => a + b)
```

Comment: This doesn't really do the job, a and b will be Option here inside the match, I want to convert them to Int or return 0 otherwise

Comment: Sorry. Will fix in minute.

Comment: You still miss the cases `(Some(a), _)` and `(_, Some(b)) `

Comment: @pme  `_` mean all other cases. Including `(Some(_), None)`, `(None, Some(_))`, `(None, None)`.

Comment: @talex sure but if a is Some(4) and b is None I want the result 4 not 0;)

Comment: Oh. Then you can look at Argurth answer. Or at my update.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution with a Seq:

```
Seq(a,b).flatten.sum
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to default to `0` use this:

```
a.getOrElse(0) + b.getOrElse(0)
```

If you want to check that both values are valid, do this:

```
a.map(av => b.map(av + _))
```

or this

```
for {
  av <- a
  bv <- b
} yield av + bv
```

Both will give `None` if either `a` or `b` is `None`, otherwise it will give `Some(a+b)`. Use `getOrElse(0)` on the result if you want the result to default to `0` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do :

```
(a, b) match {
  case (Some(sa), Some(sb)) => sa + sb
  case _ => 0
}
```

You could also do :

```
(a, b) match {
  case (Some(sa), Some(sb)) => sa + sb
  case (Some(sa), None) => sa
  case (None, Some(sb)) => sb
  case _ => 0
}
```

If you want to consider the cases where only one of them is equal to None

Answer (score 0):

Using `Seq` and `map` as required in question,

```
Seq(a,b).map(_.getOrElse(BigDecimal(0))).sum
```

( where `a` and `b` are of `Option[BigDecimal]` type )

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you want to do.

```
val a = Some(1)
val b = Some(2)

  val ans = (a, b) match {
    case (Some(a1), Some(b1)) => a1 + b1

    case _ => 0
  }
println(ans) // 3
```

you can also do like this:

```
a.getOrElse(0) + b.getOrElse(0)
```

Comment: Why create a tuple and then unpick it again?!

Comment: @Tim that's not wrong? why -1?  i don't know what exactly he wants i just showed him a way to do what author wants.

Comment: It is not wrong, it is just a bad answer because there is no need to create a tuple and then pick it apart again. The OP stated that he has two values, not a tuple.